# How to delete record using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to delete record from database using AJAX. The confirmation window does not appear so that the record can be deleted. here is the code..

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];
$p = $_GET['p'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM course_details WHERE sem='" . $q . "' AND branch='" . $p . "' ORDER BY course_codes ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);        
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo '<tr class="record">';
  echo "<td>" . $row['course_codes'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['course_names'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['course_instructors'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['course_credits'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td><div align="center"><a href="#" id="' . $row['course_id'] . '" class="delbutton" title="Click To Delete">delete</a></div></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($bd);
?>
```

Here $p and $q are send by an AJAX script from another page. It is working fine. The records are displayed as expected. Deletion works using AJAX if i do not use AJAX to display records.The script I am using to delete is:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".delbutton").click(function(){
var element = $(this);
var del_id = element.attr("id");
var info = 'id=' + del_id;
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?")){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "deleteCourse.php",
        data: info,
        success: function(){   
    }
});
    $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
    .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

deleteCourse.php

```
if($_GET['id']){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $id = mysql_escape_string($id);
}
$del = "DELETE from course_details where course_id = '$id'";

$result = mysql_query($del);
```

Comment: It seems that every day we are tasked with the duty to instruct new developers to escape and validate user input.

Comment: @Jazza: that's not what he asked...

Comment: @Jahaan - "Deletion works using AJAX if i do not use AJAX to display records", unfortunately you didn't show just this piece of code.

Comment: @Lame-up-duck - but @Jazza is still right. And the use of the `mysql` interface has long been deprecated and should be replaced by `PDO`, or `mysqli`at least...

Comment: @Lame-up-duck: plz don't be angry...He may be suffered by such questions.The fact is that we the new developers can not proceed without your help..so plz keep it up

Comment: @ErnestV: Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434125/how-to-retrieve-data-from-database-based-on-the-value-of-two-drop-down-list-usin

Comment: @Jahaan I agree with all of you but we cannot say on each post where mysql word appears, the very same things about mysqli or pdo.. Let beginners broke arms and legs, they will learn better. That's my personal opinion, not a critic to you. Sorry if I seemed angry :) PS: I think that the best option is to use a framework and forget about this stuffs :)

Comment: @ Lame-up-duck : Thanx for suggestion..Which framework you prefer.

Comment: @Jahaan: I prefer Zend but there are tons of frameworks. The choice must be weighted by your needs.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because you are creating dynamic elements so you have to use a delagate   `$(document).on()` inorder to bind the click event to the elements.
 Here is the corrected code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $(document).on('click','.delbutton',function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var del_id = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + del_id;
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?")){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "deleteCourse.php",
                data: info,
                success: function(){  } 
            });
        }
        return false;
        });
        });
    </script>
```

and your deletCourse.php

```
if($_GET['id']){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $id = mysql_escape_string($id);
}
$del = "DELETE from course_details where course_id = ".$id."";

$result = mysql_query($del);
```

Hope this helps, Thank you

Comment: @Jahaan is the confirm box displaying

Comment: :No..thats the problem

Comment: @Jahaan, I have upadated the code, if its not working, please delete that done() completely and check

Comment: @Jahaan jus to check whether the ajax call is working am removing the animation after the ajax call , check this code now

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

 <a href="#" id="1" onclick="del(this.id);return false;">delete</a>
 <a href="#" id="2" onclick="del(this.id);return false;">delete</a>
 <a href="#" id="3" onclick="del(this.id);return false;">delete</a>
 <a href="#" id="4" onclick="del(this.id);return false;">delete</a>
 <a href="#" id="5" onclick="del(this.id);return false;">delete</a>
```

javascript

```
function del(id)
{
 var info = 'id=' + id;
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?")){
        var html = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php",
        data: info,
        async: false
        }).responseText;

        if(html == "success")
        {
            $("#delete").html("delete success.");
            return true;

        }
        else
        {
            $("#captchaStatus").html("incorrect. Please try again");

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

ajax file

```
if($_GET['id']){
$id=$_GET['id'];
$id = mysql_escape_string($id);
}
$del = "DELETE from course_details where course_id = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($del);
if($result)
{
echo "success";
}
```

Comment: the confirmation box does not appear, also it does not delete data.....shows no error

Comment: @ Arun Kumar: this one also does not work..the ajax code i am using is fine.. I am using the same code in different places in my project.But here it does not work..The reason is that the data is populated using php after getting the id send by ajax...you please see the link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434125/how-to-retrieve-data-from-database-based-on-the-value-of-two-drop-down-list-usin

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ user2169355: the script i posted works fine if i use only php without using AJAX to retrieve data from database

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
function del(id)
{

 var info = 'id=' + id;
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?")){
        var html = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "deletCourse.php",
        data: info,
        async: false ,
         success: function() {
    window.location.reload(true);}
        }).responseText;


    }
}
</script>

<?php
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("cart");
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `details`");
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>NO of Items</th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  echo '<tr class="record">';
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['num'] . "</td>";

  echo '<td><div align="center"><a href="#"  id="' . $row['id'] . '" onclick="del('.$row['id'].')">delete</a></div></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($link);
?>
```